# how to upload and read .csv file in jquery

Tags: jquery, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read csv file in jquery using codeigniter framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695164/how-to-read-csv-file-in-jquery-using-codeigniter-framework)

suppose this is my .csv

fileempId,lastName,firstName,middleName,street1,street2,city,state,zip,gender,birthDate,ssn,empStatus,joinDate,workStation,location,custom1,workState,salary,payFrequency,FITWStatus,FITWExemptions,DD1Routing,DD1Account,DD1Amount,DD1AmountCode,DD1Checking,DD2Routing,DD2Account,DD2Amount,DD2AmountCode,DD2Checking
1,Dela Cruz,Juano,Santos,,,,,,1,,,Part Time Internship,, asd Division, Makati,one, asd,150,Bi Weekly,Not Applicable,100,,,,,,1234,9876,100,SAVINGS,BLANK
3,Palogan,Ralph,,,,,,,1,11-Mar-11,,Full Time Contract,2-Mar-11, sdf Department, pasay,, ,,,Not Applicable,,,,,,,,,,,
5,San,Goku,,,,hidden leaf,,,1,11-Mar-11,,,,,,,,,,Not Applicable,0,,,,,,,,,,

suppose this is my html code

```
<label>Choose File:</label><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="button" id="importButton" value="Import" name="importButton" />
```

how to get the values of that file and show it to user using jquery?

Comment: That's not a CSV file. But anyway, ignoring why you'd need to show a user a file from their own filesystem: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/

Look at the link.  Add jquery-csv.js in your HTML.  Then use,

```
$.csv.function(csv, {options}, callback);
```

Client-Side: (ie browser) - import via the script element.

```
<script src="jquery-csv.js"></script>
```

Server-Side: (ie Node.js) - Import via the standard CommonJS approach.

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('./jquery.csv.js');
```

Usage
Each one of the methods can be called with the following form:
    $.csv.function(csv, {options}, callback);

Comment: how to do that.,,maybe an example code,.,.

Comment: @webghost There's a demo for that http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/file-handling.html. Seriously, tho. Take a minute to read the documentation.