# how to read csv file in jquery using codeigniter framework

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv

suppose this is my csv file

```
fileempId,lastName,firstName,middleName,street1,street2,city,state,zip,gender,birthDate,ssn,empStatus,joinDate,workStation,location,custom1,workState,salary,payFrequency,FITWStatus,FITWExemptions,DD1Routing,DD1Account,DD1Amount,DD1AmountCode,DD1Checking,DD2Routing,DD2Account,DD2Amount,DD2AmountCode,DD2Checking
1,Dela Cruz,Juano,Santos,,,,,,1,,,Part Time Internship,, asd Division, Makati,one, asd,150,Bi Weekly,Not Applicable,100,,,,,,1234,9876,100,SAVINGS,BLANK
3,Palogan,Ralph,,,,,,,1,11-Mar-11,,Full Time Contract,2-Mar-11, sdf Department, pasay,, ,,,Not Applicable,,,,,,,,,,, 5,San,Goku,,,,hidden leaf,,,1,11-Mar-11,,,,,,,,,,Not Applicable,0,,,,,,,,,,
```

this is my form

```
<label>Choose File:</label><font color="#FF0000">*</font>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="button" id="importButton" value="Import" name="importButton" />
```

how to read the data in csv and store it to mysql database(codeigniter)? Any example code on how to do it,.

please see what is wrong with my code below,..,

my view page containing the jquery and form,,.

```
<td><label>Choose File:</label><font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
       <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>
         <td><label>Import Type </label><font color="#FF0000">*</font></td>
         <td><select name="importname" id="importname" style="width:130px;">
                 <option value="" selected>--Select--</option>
                 <?php 
                       foreach($fields as $data){
                            print '<option value="'.$data->import_id.'">'.$data->name.'</option>';
                       }
                 ?>
             </select></td>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#importData").click(function(e) {
            var file = $('#file').val();
            var type = $('#importname').val();
            $.post("<?php print base_url().'index.php/MyController/readExcel'?>",{file: file, type: type},
                function(data)
                        {
                        if(data!='success')
                        {
                            error_message(data);    

                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Upload Succcessfull!");
                        }
            });

               });
});

</script>
```

my controller

```
function readExcel(){
    $file=$this->input->post('file');
    $type=$this->input->post('type');
    $this->load->library('csvreader');
    $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file($file);

    $data['csvData'] =  $result;
    $this->load->view('MyViews/showImportFile', $data);  

}
```

my library

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class csvreader {

    var $fields;            /** columns names retrieved after parsing */ 
    var $separator = ';';    /** separator used to explode each line */
    var $enclosure = '"';    /** enclosure used to decorate each field */

    var $max_row_size = 4096;    /** maximum row size to be used for decoding */

    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

        $content    =   array();
        $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   1;
        while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {            
            if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
               $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);
               if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                   $arr    =   array();
                   $new_values =   array();
                   $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                   for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                       if($keys[$j] != ""){
                           $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                       }
                   }

                   $content[$i]=   $arr;
                   $i++;
               }
           }
       }
       fclose($file);
       return $content;
   }

   function escape_string($data){
       $result =   array();
       foreach($data as $row){
           $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
       }
       return $result;
   }
```

}

i am getting an error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(export 1.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/csvreader.php

can anybody out there help me please!!!

Comment: Have you tried Google? https://github.com/thebizztech/getcsv-PHP-Library-for-Codeigniter.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com has a good source

Answer (score 0):

I use this library to convert array to some other data format or vice versa.

[CI - Rest Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

There you can find library/class Format (Format.php) that you can use to convert CSV to array then save it into your database. This class also support other format:

- xml – almost any programming language can read XML
- json – useful for JavaScript and increasingly PHP apps.
- csv – open with spreadsheet programs
- html – a simple HTML table
- php – Representation of PHP code that can be eval()’ed
- serialize – Serialized data that can be unserialized in PHP

**EDIT:**

This library works on CSV with delimiter "\n" on each row and "," on each of column, you can use it like this:

```
$this->load->library('format');

$string_csv = "YOUR CSV";        
$result = $this->format->factory($string_csv, 'csv')->to_array();

var_dump($result);
```

Just that simple. However as I said above if your have another delimiter then you have to adjust the library as your need. Here the main function to convert CSV to array:

```
function _from_csv($string)
{
    $data = array();

    // Splits
    $rows = explode("\n", trim($string));
    $headings = explode(',', array_shift($rows));
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        // The substr removes " from start and end
        $data_fields = explode('","', trim(substr($row, 1, -1)));

        if (count($data_fields) == count($headings))
        {
            $data[] = array_combine($headings, $data_fields);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

My example will work on this standard CSV format:

```
Heading1, Heading2, Heading3
"1","John","London"
"2","Brian","Texas"
```

Comment: @webghost where's your code, is it in your question above? Your CSV sample is hard to convert since the delimiter for each row is `space`. See my CSV sample.

Comment: @SubRedi have edited my code above,.,.can you please take a look at it,.., if what part did i make error(s).,,. can you modify my code,.,.

Comment: excluded the sample csv above,.. please see my edited post,,. tnx in advance

Comment: @webghost sory for late reply. Based on your edited question you can't directly read file from `$file=$this->input->post('file');` because it is not saved yet on your server. You need to first upload the file to your server ([you can use CI upload](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)) then start to read it using your csvreader library. I suggest that you first create dummy CSV file on your server without uploading it to see if your csv reader works as you expected. You can then add upload function once your csv lib works.

Comment: how to do that,.,.or can you give me sample code on how to upload csv file using jquery in codeigniter.,,.please tnx

Comment: itried using CI UPLOAD but the allowed types are for images only,..,do i include csv on the allowed types and remove the maxlenght etc.,,

Comment: @webghost you can simply set it like this `$config['allowed_types']='csv';` in your `do_upload()` function. You can then get uploaded path like this:  `$data=$this->upload->data();  $file_path=$data['full_path'];`.

Comment: i get the error The upload path does not appear to be valid. i had created a folder uploads in the ci root directory,.,.my config code is like this.,.,     $config['base_url']= "http://localhost/myhr";  and my do_upload function       $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

Comment: my csv reader works because i tested it with a sample csv file now,,the problem is that i cant upload a file into the server,,using the ci upload that you had suggested,..cant have a copy on uploads folder,,.what shall i do to resolve this problem,..thankz

Comment: @webghost have you created the writable folder `uploads` inside your base url folder (`myhr`)?

Comment: That's weird. Well I might not be able to help you for this since I can only guess but it still does not come up to solution. This error is generated by `system/libraries/Upload.php` under function `validate_upload_path()`. Try to debug/log under this function, you may find the culprit. Good luck. Let me know if you have difficulties for this.

Comment: cant resolve the issue,.,can you please give me code wherein it allows to upload a csv file,,.match the csv fields to a fields in a certain table in db and if the fields match then it will insert whatever record the csv has,..,please thank you in advance,,.

Comment: @webghost see my another answer that I have also created a sample for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that actually you want to upload your CSV file first to your server then check if the CSV fields/headers match to one of your database table fields to insert the row, here the sample code I made:

CSV Reader (based from this **[library](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/03/reading-csv-file-in-codeigniter/)** with some adjustments):

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
* CSVReader Class
*
* $Id: csvreader.php 147 2007-07-09 23:12:45Z Pierre-Jean $
*
* Allows to retrieve a CSV file content as a two dimensional array.
* The first text line shall contains the column names.
*
* @author        Pierre-Jean Turpeau
* @link        http://www.codeigniter.com/wiki/CSVReader
*/
class CSVReader {

    var $fields;        /** columns names retrieved after parsing */
    var $separator = ',';    /** separator used to explode each line */

    /**
     * Parse a text containing CSV formatted data.
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    array
     */
    function parse_text($p_Text) {
        $lines = explode("\n", $p_Text);
        return $this->parse_lines($lines);
    }

    /**
     * Parse a file containing CSV formatted data.
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    string
     * @return    array
     */
    function parse_file($p_Filepath) {
        $lines = file($p_Filepath);
        return $this->parse_lines($lines);
    }
    /**
     * Parse an array of text lines containing CSV formatted data.
     *
     * @access    public
     * @param    array
     * @return    array
     */
    function parse_lines($p_CSVLines) {    
        $content = FALSE;
        foreach( $p_CSVLines as $line_num => $line ) {                        
            if( $line != '' ) { // skip empty lines
                $line = trim($line);

                $elements = explode($this->separator, $line);

                if( !is_array($content) ) { // the first line contains fields names
                    $this->fields = $elements;
                    $content = array();
                } else {
                    $item = array();
                    foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {
                        if( isset($elements[$id]) ) {
                            $item[$field] = $elements[$id];
                        }
                    }
                    $content[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Get fields
     */
    public function get_fields(){
        return $this->fields;
    }
}
```

Do upload handler on CI:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('csvfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('csv_upload', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

        // start to read the CSV file
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        $file_path = $upload_data['full_path'];

        $csv_data = $this->csvreader->parse_file($file_path); 
        $csv_fields = $this->csvreader->get_fields();

        // list your database table
        $tables = $this->db->list_tables();
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $fields = $this->db->list_fields($table);

            if($fields == $csv_fields) // match to one of database table
            {
                // insert the record
                foreach($csv_data as $row){                        
                    $this->db->insert($table, $row);
                }
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'upload_data' => $upload_data,
            'csv_data' => $csv_data,
        );

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Download full sample **[HERE](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/78566197/ci_.zip)**. You can find sample of CSV file inside folder `uploads`.

Comment: seems that my error is the path the file has to be upload.,,.my config file is.,.$config['base_url'] = "localhost/myhr";,.,.what would be the upload path? mine is $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; i have created the folder uploads.,. i am getting the error The upload path does not appear to be valid. –

Comment: @webghost sory for late reply, hmm try to set your `$config['base_url']` to blank and let CI guess the protocol, domain and path to your installation. And if you use `.htaccess mod_rewrite` on your CI you should also set the `$config['index_page']` to blank.

Comment: Yes That works but how do i integrate it to my system,,. i had stated above my configuration in base url,.,how do i resolve the issue.,., please help,.,tnx

Comment: @webghost what actually is your issue? There is already sample code for you. Have you tried it yet? I mean a sample will not directly suit to your need, you have to do some adjustments there.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your CSVReader function. It gives me perfect result as per my need. I also like your idea to check if the CSV fields/headers match to one of your database table fields to insert the row. It gives result array as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Years] => 1888
            [Make1] => Acura
            [Make2] => Honda
            [Make] => Honda
            [] => Honda
            [Makes] => Toyota
)
```

I have also tried CSVReader library at this location.
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CSVReader
But it gives result array with values imploded by comma(,) as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Years,Make1,Make2,Make,,Makes,Make] => 1888,Acura,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda
        )
)
```

Now SubRed, in your CSVReader function, I have made changes to CSV file's first row name with whitespace at the end. But after that in the CI controller, while I am checking that fields/headers/column_name exists in CSV file with `array_key_exists('column_name',$csvdata)`, it returns false/none because of whitespace in the `column_name` field at the end. So I have updated your code.

Please refer below updated code and give me any suggestions if any.

EDIT :-
Make changes to the foreach loop in parse_lines function in CSVReader file =>

```
foreach( $this->fields as $id => $field ) {  
    //echo $id;
    //echo $field;
    //In CSV File, trim(remove both end whitespaces) the first line which contains fields names
    $field = trim($field);
    if( isset($elements[$id]) ) 
    {
        $item[trim($field)] = trim($elements[$id]);//In CSV File, trim all the file data
    }
 }
```